# Named tuple defined in one pyhton-module not recognised by another python module

Tags: python, attributeerror, namedtuple

I have defined the named-tuple in one function of the `TLV.py` module and return the same type in this function.

But when I call the function defined in TLV.py in another module `ISO8583.py`, the named-tuple keys are not recognized.

In my following example, I have defined `EMVTags = collections.namedtuple('EMVTags', 'Tag TagName Value')` in `def parse` of `TLV.py` and retun value is same as the type of `EMVTags`.

Now I call the `parse` in `ISO8583.py` , the `Tag`,`TagName` and `Value` are not identified as it gives me the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'TagName'
```

But it works fine when I run in Pycharm and not working when I run with windows command prompt.

**TLV.py**

```
def parse(self, tlv_string):
        """
        """
        parsed_data = list()

        EMVTags = collections.namedtuple('EMVTags', 'Tag TagName Value')
        self.tlv_string = tlv_string

        i = 0
        while i < len(self.tlv_string):
            tag_found = False

            for tag_length in self.tag_lengths:
                for tag, tag_name in self.tags.items():
                    if self.tlv_string[i:i + tag_length].lower() == tag.lower():
                        try:
                            value_length = int(self.tlv_string[i + tag_length:i + tag_length + 2], 16)
                        except ValueError:
                            raise ValueError('Parse error: tag ' + tag + ' has incorrect data length')

                        value_start_position = i + tag_length + 2
                        value_end_position = i + tag_length + 2 + value_length * 2

                        if value_end_position > len(self.tlv_string):
                            raise ValueError('Parse error: tag ' + tag + ' declared data of length ' + str(
                                value_length) + ', but actual data length is ' + str(
                                int(len(self.tlv_string[value_start_position - 1:-1]) / 2)))

                        value = self.tlv_string[value_start_position:value_end_position]
                        parsed_data.append(EMVTags(Tag=tag, TagName=tag_name, Value=value))
                        i = value_end_position
                        tag_found = True

            if not tag_found:
                    msg = 'Unknown tag found: ' + self.tlv_string[i:i + 10]
                    raise ValueError(msg)
        return parsed_data
```

**ISO8583.py**

```
def ParseRawMessage(ISO8583TextFile):
    with open(ISO8583TextFile, 'rb') as in_file:
        hex_bytes = in_file.read()
        IsoStr = hex_bytes.decode('ascii')
        Iso8583 = ISO8583()
        try:
            Iso8583.setIsoContent(IsoStr)
        except ISOErrors.InvalidMTI as error:
            print("{0}".format(error))

        bitsAndValuesDictionary = Iso8583.getBitsAndValues()
        print('\n\n### ISO8583 Message ###\n')
        for v in bitsAndValuesDictionary:
            print(' %s (BIT-%s) = %s\n' % (v['name'], v['bit'], v['value']))
            if v['bit'] == '55':
                Field55StringValue = v['value'][4:]
        if Field55StringValue:
            from pytlv.TLV import TLV
            tlv = TLV()
            try:
                EmvTagValueList = tlv.parse(Field55StringValue)
                print('\n\n\t### EMVTags of Field-55 ###\n')
                for TagValue in EmvTagValueList:
                    print(TagValue.TagName + ' ({})'.format(TagValue.Tag) + ' = {}'.format(TagValue.Value))
            except ValueError as error:
                print("Invalid field/fields in Field-55 ")
```

Comment: Why are you creating the definition for the `namestuple` in the function and not on top-level?

Comment: Please let me know ,what is the issue of creating inside the function scope? And why it works when I run on pyCharm?

Comment: I don't know if or why this is the issue, it's just odd. Also, the error seems not to be that it does not recognize the attribute, but that the thing has the entirely wrong type -- `str`, instead of your tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The `namedtuple()` function is basically a class factory. You need to import that class to other modules to use it.
I would suggest doing this and importing `EMVTags` in your other module.

```
#this line is in the top of the file
import collections
EMVTags = collections.namedtuple('EMVTags', 'Tag TagName Value')
#...

def parse(self, tlv_string):
    """
    """
    parsed_data = list()

    self.tlv_string = tlv_string

    i = 0
    while i < len(self.tlv_string):
        tag_found = False

        for tag_length in self.tag_lengths:
            for tag, tag_name in self.tags.items():
                if self.tlv_string[i:i + tag_length].lower() == tag.lower():
                    try:
                        value_length = int(self.tlv_string[i + tag_length:i + tag_length + 2], 16)
                    except ValueError:
                        raise ValueError('Parse error: tag ' + tag + ' has incorrect data length')

                    value_start_position = i + tag_length + 2
                    value_end_position = i + tag_length + 2 + value_length * 2

                    if value_end_position > len(self.tlv_string):
                        raise ValueError('Parse error: tag ' + tag + ' declared data of length ' + str(
                            value_length) + ', but actual data length is ' + str(
                            int(len(self.tlv_string[value_start_position - 1:-1]) / 2)))

                    value = self.tlv_string[value_start_position:value_end_position]
                    parsed_data.append(EMVTags(Tag=tag, TagName=tag_name, Value=value))
                    i = value_end_position
                    tag_found = True

        if not tag_found:
                msg = 'Unknown tag found: ' + self.tlv_string[i:i + 10]
                raise ValueError(msg)
    return parsed_data
```

Comment: I did do your suggestions, unfortunately, I had no luck. Also why on the first place, it works when it is run on pyCharm.

Comment: In batch file    ,   python C:\Projects\TripTickAT\ISO8583_Payment\ISO8583.py  C:\Projects\TripTickAT\ISO8583_Payment\ISO8583.txt where txt file is an argument

Comment: Why it recognizes as 'str' object whereas it recognizes as name-tuple while running in pycharm.

Comment: @raj That is indeed pretty odd. Maybe it will help checking how pycharm is running your script ?

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out the issue.

The actual root cause of the issue is the path of the TLV.py. Because I have done the `pip install for pyTlv` which went in the `site-packages` directory in `windows`.

Then I keep the source of pyTlv lib into my project and make some changes for name-tuple type instead of str type return.

So when I use it from `pycharm`, it correctly picks up the modified version of TLV.py but when I use the `windows cmd` line , it picks up from the original `TLV.py` which I did via `pip install`.